# Is this cheap extension cord safely rated for 1625W?

Tags: power, gauge, awg

Comparing two cables that I have, a cheap extension cord and an expensive "heavy duty" extension cord, both are rated for the same load.

Is this an inflated rating or is it accurate for the white extension cable?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd mainly be worried about contact resistance and copper area. The orange one also has a second layer of insulation because it is intended for outdoor use, more plastic/rubber doesnt necessarily mean more current. (it can even  mean lower rated current, due to lower heat dissipation.. some of them you shouldnt even use while in a roll because it heats up too much)

Comment: Usually there is marking on the cable. [Like this](https://i.imgur.com/JKjAJg8.jpg) Either printed or molded. Find it, what does it say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between the two lies in isolation, not the conductor. Notice how the orange one is for outdoor usage, so it has to have one more layer of isolation.

For the 13 A current rating, AWG 14 would definitively suffice; that's a conductor diameter of 1.6 mm, so really not that much.

Also, the orange one has one conductor more – so, another reason it's thicker. Having seen industrial and event/stage cabling, I'd really not call your orange cable "heavy duty", by the way. It does look like the minimum effort you'd have to go through to rate something for outdoor usage.

So, I don't know why you'd distrust the rating of the white one; it looks fine for indoor usage, even if I don't like this slightly US-typical type of 2-conductor cabling, since it has a tendency to tangle.